# Why is "AppleSequencer" limited to 280.00 BPM?

Tags: audiokit

I've started using AppleSequencer in my app and was wondering why it is limited to 280bpm?

When setting tempos above 280bpm like `sequencer.setTempo(BPM(300.00))` the sequencer still plays and returns 280.00 in `sequencer.tempo`

Would be awesome to make faster tempos possible. If not it would be great to get a warning in the console when setting tempos above 280.

Answer (score 0):

The setTempo method in AppleSequencer.swift clamps that value to the range of 10 to 280.

`let constrainedTempo = (10 ... 280).clamp(bpm)`

You could write a Pull Request to add a comment to setTempo in AppleSequencer.swift.

`if bpm > 280 || bpm < 10 { Log("bpm out of range") }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are there any plans to increase the maximum bpm amount? With 280bpm it's kind of limited.

Comment: I'm not sure why they set it to 280 max but I'm sure they would be fine with the change. The best way to get changes introduced is to explain your use case and submit a pull request on the git repo. I'm not a part of AudioKit but I've been submitting updates using PRs lately.

Comment: Christian, how are you setting your max tempo value? Are you using programmatic UI or a UISlider in Storyboards? Is it possible that your max tempo is set somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Christian,

If you use the **AudioKit 5** Sequencer that's available when you import `AudioKit` and `AudioKitEX` from the Swift Package Manager, it doesn't have a tempo limit.

`sequencer.tempo = 300`